# Python integration with poles

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to integrate an expression with poles, something like:

[image: integral]

where the poles are at z = ib-a, ib+a, -ib-a, -ib+a

Python has a range of [integration tools in scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html), but I don't know if there are Python functions to do this type of integration, or how to specify the poles in the integrand.

Comment: If you were integrating over real values,  `scipy.integrate.quad` would have argument *points* for singularities etc., http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html

Comment: Do you want to do numeric or symbolic integration? In the latter case, [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/de/index.html) could become your friend.

Comment: @kazemakase it doesn't look like SymPy can compute a symbolic solution to this. Even WolframAlpha doesn't give an answer, which suggests a nice symbolic closed form might not exist (at least for symbolic `a`, `b`, and `c`).

Comment: Aren't there some additional poles from the tanh() function? For example tanh(z) will have poles when cos(i.x) = 0. I suspect the correct answer to this question is to use contour integration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration), which would reduce your integral to a sum over a set of residues that you could probably calculate algebraically.